# Using Optware packages and startup scripts on dd-wrt router

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, dd-wrt

I'm trying to run a mumble server (umurmur) on my dd-wrt router (Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H). I flashed one of the recent community versions of dd-wrt on the device (SVN Rev.: 23320), it has an Atheros CPU inside.

After that I mounted a USB pendrive into the filesystem using these guides ([Guide 1](http://www.howtogeek.com/98408/how-to-install-additional-software-on-your-router-dd-wrt/), [Guide 2](http://g300nh.blogspot.de/2010/06/software-installation-on-dd-wrt-part-1.html)) and created writable directories. Here is my startup-script saved to nvram (via web-gui)

EDIT: USB pendrive should be partioned before using it with DD-Wrt.

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 5
insmod mbcache
insmod jbd
insmod ext3

mkdir '/mnt/part1'
mkdir '/mnt/part2'
mount -t ext3 -o noatime /dev/sda5 /mnt/part1   # /dev/sda5 -> partition on USB pendrive
mount -t ext3 -o noatime /dev/sda7 /mnt/part2   # /dev/sda7 -> partition on USB pendrive
swapon /dev/sda6                                # /dev/sda6 -> partition on USB pendrive

sleep 2
if [ -f /mnt/part1/optware.enable ];then 
#mount -o bind /mnt/part2 /mnt/part1/root
mount -o bind /mnt/part1        /jffs
mount -o bind /mnt/part1/etc    /etc
mount -o bind /mnt/part1/opt    /opt 
mount -o bind /mnt/part1/root   /tmp/root
else
exit
fi

if [ -d /opt/usr ]; then
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/usr/lib:/jffs/usr/lib:/jffs/usr/local/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/jffs/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/opt/usr/bin:/opt/usr/sbin
export IPKG_INSTROOT=/opt
else
exit
fi
```

The script works well and I can use opkg to install packages. I can also run umurmur manually but I'm struggling on making umurmur autostart. I recognized that the umurmur startup script placed in `/opt/etc/init.d/` requires arguments like `start` and `stop` but it seems they are called without any arguments.

Another way described [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Startup_Scripts) did not work too.

Has anyone a working solution on problems like these? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Optware runs on Broadcom routers only.    Your's has an Atheros chipset.

Taken from this page: [Link](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware,_the_Right_Way)

Comment: The site links to a thread, which describes the opkg-distribution method for Atheros devices.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear i the page you referred to has changed - and indeed my setup is fairly different to yours, but to get scripts working on startup I did the following -

- mkdir -p /jffs/etc/config
- copy script into /jffs/etc/config directory, renaming it to end with .startup
- chmod 755 /jffs/etc/config/scriptname.startup